# Can't compile a file cpp while using filesystem library with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, filesystems, c++17, sfml

I was trying to make a game using SFML and C++17 standard compiled with gcc.
When im trying to load the resources from a specified directory, im getting this huge output from the compiler.
This is my compiler.bat:

```
    g++ -std=c++17 "..\Gioco\src\main\com\*.cpp" "..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\*.cpp" "..\Gioco\src\main\com\item\*.cpp" "..\Gioco\src\main\com\tile\*.cpp" "..\Gioco\src\main\com\hud\*.cpp" -I "D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include" -L "D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\lib" -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -o "D:\Programmazione\Giochi\Gioco Con Edo\PierciangeloSalvaLaTerra\bin\Gioco.exe" -lstdc++fs
```

This is the Error I Get:

```
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\..\\ResourceHandler.hpp:6,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\Enemy.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:60: note:   std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:37,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/locale:43,
                 from D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/System/Utf.hpp:33,
                 from D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/System/String.hpp:32,
                 from D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/System.hpp:42,
                 from D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from D:\Programmazione\Giochi\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\Entity.hpp:4,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\LivingEntity.hpp:4,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\Enemy.hpp:4,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\Enemy.cpp:1:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tuple:1439:5: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::tuple<_Tps ...>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)'
     operator!=(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tuple:1439:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/filesystem:37,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\..\\ResourceHandler.hpp:6,
                 from ..\Gioco\src\main\com\entity\Enemy.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::tuple<_Tps ...>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
```

This is Where I load the resources:

```
static void loadResources()
{
    std::cout << "Loading Resource...\n";
    std::string path = "../resources/textures/entity";
    for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        sf::Texture texture = sf::Texture();
        std::string filePath = entry.path().generic_string();
        if (texture.loadFromFile(filePath))
        {
            ENTITIES.push_back(texture);
            std::cout << "Loadedi: " << entry.path() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Resource Loaded\n================================\n";
}
```

Someone can explain me why this happen, and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Please ensure wverything is included in the question itself, and as text.

Comment: Ok, now it's good?

Comment: What's the use of `filePath` instead of just doing `texture.loadFromFile(entry.path())`?

Comment: Ok, i can simplify that. But the problem is that i can't compile the cose when i use ththing on filesystem

Comment: According to [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78870), it was fixed for gcc 9, so you should probably update.